# csv2md format output using awk

Tags: shell, awk

I need to create a markdown formatted output using awk which is similar to table results that we get using mysql. In other words, I'm trying to mimic https://www.convertcsv.com/csv-to-markdown.htm
using the below input.

```
id|type|cost|date|ship
0|A|223|201603|PORT
0|A|22|201602|PORT
0|A|422|201601|DOCK
1|B|3213|201602|DOCK
1|B|3213|201601|PORT
2|C|2321|201601|DOCK
```

The output I'm looking for is below

```
------------------------------
|id |type |cost |  date |ship |
------------------------------
|0  |A    |223  |201603 |PORT |
|0  |A    |22   |201602 |PORT |
|0  |A    |422  |201601 |DOCK |
|1  |B    |3213 |201602 |DOCK |
|1  |B    |3213 |201601 |PORT |
|2  |C    |2321 |201601 |DOCK |
------------------------------
```

My first attempt is to get the max size for each column and use that in the formatting when printing. But the below one is not working as expected.

```
awk -F"|" ' 
NR==1 { hdr=$0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { a[i]=length($i) } next } 
{ for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { ;a[i]=length($i)>a[i]?length($i):a[i] } content[NR]=$0 } 
END { 
for(i in a) len+=a[i]+2;
$0=""; OFS="-"; len++; NF=len; print ;
n=split(hdr,arr,FS); 
for(i=1;i<=n;i++) 
  {  printf("%6s |",arr[i]); }  # instead of 6 i want to pass a[i] ==> "%6" a[i] "s |" is not working
print "";

} 
' data.txt
```

How to fix it and get the required output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This requires a 2-pass approach, either of the following would work:

A) reading the input file twice so it uses very little memory:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
NR==FNR {
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        wid = length($i)
        wids[i] = (wid > wids[i] ? wid : wids[i])
    }
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    totWid = NF+1
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        totWid += wids[i]
    }
    dashes = sprintf("%*s",totWid,"")
    gsub(/ /,"-",dashes)
    print dashes
    printf "%s", OFS
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%*s%s", wids[i], $i, OFS
    }
    print ""
    print dashes
    next
}
{
    printf "%s", OFS
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%-*s%s", wids[i], $i, OFS
    }
    print ""
}
END { print dashes }
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file file
--------------------------
|id|type|cost|  date|ship|
--------------------------
|0 |A   |223 |201603|PORT|
|0 |A   |22  |201602|PORT|
|0 |A   |422 |201601|DOCK|
|1 |B   |3213|201602|DOCK|
|1 |B   |3213|201601|PORT|
|2 |C   |2321|201601|DOCK|
--------------------------
```

B) storing  the whole file in memory and then the 2nd pass is an array traversal rather than reading the file again which should run faster if you have enough memory to do it:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS=OFS="|" }
{
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        wid = length($i)
        wids[i] = (wid > wids[i] ? wid : wids[i])
        vals[NR,i] = $i
    }
}
END {
    totWid = NF+1
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        totWid += wids[i]
    }
    dashes = sprintf("%*s",totWid,"")
    gsub(/ /,"-",dashes)
    print dashes
    printf "%s", OFS
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        printf "%*s%s", wids[i], vals[1,i], OFS
    }
    print ""
    print dashes

    for (lineNr=2; lineNr<=NR; lineNr++) {
        printf "%s", OFS
        for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
            printf "%-*s%s", wids[i], vals[lineNr,i], OFS
        }
        print ""
    }
    print dashes
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
--------------------------
|id|type|cost|  date|ship|
--------------------------
|0 |A   |223 |201603|PORT|
|0 |A   |22  |201602|PORT|
|0 |A   |422 |201601|DOCK|
|1 |B   |3213|201602|DOCK|
|1 |B   |3213|201601|PORT|
|2 |C   |2321|201601|DOCK|
--------------------------
```

Comment: thanks Ed, it works.. in the code ````printf "%-*s%s", wids[i], vals[lineNr,i], OFS```` why one % is missing

Comment: Note the `*` in `%-*s` - that's where you specify the field width as one of the args, in this case `wids[i]`. `printf "%*s\n", 10, "foo"` is functionally equivalent to `printf "%"10"s\n", "foo"`. See "dynamic width and prec capability" at https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Format-Modifiers.

Answer (score 1):

There is a program for making tabular output, which is `columns -s '|' -t`, but it looses the separator `|` in its output.

You can recover that separator with `sed`, replacing each white space followed by a non white char by a `|` followed by that non white char.

Finally, `awk` helps you to add a line before and after the headers of the columns.

```
column -s '|' -t input.csv | sed -E 's/ ([^ ])/|\1/g' | awk '(NR == 1) {l = $0; gsub(/./, "-", l); print l "\n" $0 "\n" l} (NR > 1) {print} END{print l}'
```

Comment: good approximation with a one-liner, acceptable to me.. btw column command has some limitations wrt blanks.. right?....i.e not parsing well..

Comment: @stack0114106: `columns` has no problem when the separator is `|`. The problem can rise if the fields contain blanks at the level of the `sed` command.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer using the concepts from Ed.

```
awk -F"|" ' 
NR==1 { hdr=$0; for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { a[i]=length($i) } next } 
{ 
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) a[i]=length($i)>a[i]?length($i):a[i] ;
  content[NR]=$0 
} 
END { 
dashes="+";
  for(i in a) 
  {      len+=a[i]+1; 
         dash=sprintf("%*s",a[i],""); 
         gsub(/ /,"-",dash); 
         dashes=dashes dash "+" 
  }
 #Header
    print dashes;
    n=split(hdr,arr,FS); printf("|");
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++) { fmt="%" a[i] "s|" ; printf(fmt,arr[i]); } print "";
    print dashes;

 #Contents  
    for(i=2;i<=NR;i++) 
    {
     n=split(content[i],arr,FS); printf("|");
     for(j=1;j<=n;j++) { fmt="%-" a[j] "s|" ; printf(fmt,arr[j]); } print "";
    }
    print dashes
} 
' data.txt
```